# How to make a state with different parent state?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Consider a scenario of page layout for my project,

```
Father ----> His Friends Listing  
Father ----> Child ----> His Friends Listing
```

In route

```
Father - root.father  
Father-->Friends - root.father.friends  
Father-->Child - root.father.child  
Father-->Child-->Friends - root.father.child.friends
```

How can I create just one route for 'Friends' which can used for any state of parent(in ui router)? I have same controller for both the route.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define each stat, that said you can reuse the FriendsController and its template in each definition.

**UPDATE**

If you want to pragmatically define these states, you have two options:

1. Within the state configuration
2. At build time using code generation

Here is an example of the first option, within your states config you could have something like:

```
var friendStateParents = ['root.father', 'root.father.child'];    

function generateFriendStates() {

    friendStateParents.forEach(function(parent) {

       $stateProvider.state(parent + '.friends', {
            controller: 'FriendsController',
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            templateUrl: 'friends.controller.html'
       })
   })
}

generateFiendStates();
```

Comment: Is there any other way where I don't have to define each state.? I dont have any change in template and controller.